# clojure macro expand repeated code

Tags: clojure, macros

I am stuck trying to do something probably basic with clojure macro. I simplified my example to the minimal below. Let's say I have:

```
(def a {:i 0})
```

And I want to define b to something like:

```
(def b (my-func a a a a a a ... a a a a))
```

At compile time, I know how many `a` I want (for example 3). But to remove code redundancy, and for better code, I would like to parameterize the number of `a`. I would like something like:

```
(def b (my-func (some-magic-macro 3 a)))
```

that would expand to

```
(def b (my-func a a a))
```

Tried a bunch of things with macrodef, repeat, quoting etc... without much succes due to my limited understanding of clojure at this stage

Thank you people!

Comment: Why don't you just use `repeat` in the position of `some-magic-macro`? Perhaps you want this: `(def b (apply my-func (repeat 3 a)))`.

Comment: ntalbs, what I need is to macro expand at compile time:
I need to replace the following in my code:
(def b (my-func a a a a a a ... a a a a))
by
(def b (my-func (some-magic-macro 3 a)))
that would expand (at compile time) to (def b (my-func a a a))

Comment: @ntalbs Actually, this is very helpfull. Thanks!
I am still very confused how and why, but that solve my problem :)

Comment: You can check `apply` function in the documentation. Study the difference that `(+ 1 2 3 4 5)` and `(apply + [1 2 3 4 5])` will help you understand that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a macro returns a single form, you can't make `my-magic-macro` return a number of copies of the argument to be used by `my-func`. You can however include `my-func` as an argument to `my-magic-macro`, and have the complete call returned:

```
(defmacro my-magic-macro [func arg n] `(~func ~@(repeat n arg)))
```

Comment: Ahhh I see. Indeed adding my-func as an argument makes it work. Thanks all for your help!